# how to change the name of a variable in a loop using python

Tags: python

I need to create something like:

```
x1 = [1 1 1]
x2 = [2 2 2]
   .
   .
   .
xn = [n n n]
```

and for this, I was thinking of doing:

```
for i in range(whatever):
    xi = np.array([i, i, i])
```

but it doesn't work, obviously.
pleasy help me!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I highly recommend using a `dict()` or a `list()`, but what you're trying to do is fairly simple:**

```
for i in range(whatever):
    locals()[f'x{i+1}'] = np.array([i, i, i])
```

---

---

---

**Dictionary:**

```
d = {f'x{i+1}':np.array([i, i, i]) for i in range(whatever)}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [np.array([i, i, i]) for i in range(whatever)]
```

Now x is a nested list and your `xi` corresponds to `x[i]`

Comment: omg the same thoughts :-) the same think. but you are faster than me.

Answer (score 1):

you cant create names or data types or objects like that in python or any other language. use a list object, append to it and you are the person to know that each entry in the list is your "variable  Xi":

**Use list comprehension**

```
X = [np.array([i, i, i]) for index in range(100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use dynamic variable names in python, but you still can have dynamic dictionary keys.
You can use a dictionary to achieve something like this:

```py
data = {}

for i in range(100):
    data['x'+str(i)] = np.array([i, i, i])
```

Or use the comprehension method

```py
data = {'x{}'.format(i): np.array([i, i, i]) for i in range(100)}
```

Or using lists:

```py
data = [np.array([i, i, i]) for i in range(100)]
```